# When selecting #{null} item in h:selectOneMenu, f:ajax listener is not invoked

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want a selectOneMenu with the possibility to select 'null' as valid value and/or fire a f:ajax to execute the valueChange event.

My current state looks like this:

```xhtml
<h:selectOneMenu id="energySource" value="#{counter.energySourceType}"
    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" class="form-control">
  <f:selectItems value="#{buildingBean.energySourceTypeSelectItems}"/>
  <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Strom" />
  <f:ajax execute="@this" render="provider" listener="#{buildingBean.debug()}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:messages id="energySourceMessage" for="energySource" styleClass="list-inline alert alert-danger"/>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="provider">
  <h:panelGroup layout="block" class="form-group" rendered="#{empty counter.energySourceType}">
    <label>Strom-Anbieter</label>
    Strom
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

At the moment the first change from 'null' to a selectItem-value works but the change back doesn't works since 'null' as value is a workaround in JSF 1.x where the noSelectionOption="true" wasn't available. So how can I do this? It is also needed to set the energySourceType 'null', which is the value of the selectOneMenu and from my point of view doing this within the form is the easiest way, because it's in a  loop.

Comment: Have you tried with `noSelectionOption`?

Comment: Yes with the value 'true' and 'false'.

Comment: Then why you don't post it? It's the JSF-2 way to achieve it.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't posted it but I wanted it as a SelectionOption and since value = null is the same like noSO=true so it shouldn't work. But I want null as a selection option.

Comment: That should work with no problem..

Comment: No unlikely not, like I wrote before. Even if I use noSelectOption="false" it's not evaluated on the right way. The Ajax function is called but in the modell the old value is present. Every other change is taken to the modell only if I change back to 'null' it doesn't works.

Comment: Setting either `noSelectionOption="true"` or `itemValue="#{null}"` are equivalent. They have to set `null` value for your `#{counter.energySourceType}`.

Comment: Like I sad unlikely not, even my debug function which is the listener of the ajax function isn't called, but I can see with the Browser debugger, that an empty partial-response comes.

Comment: What's the signature of your listener method? It could be breaking all the cycle... Try removing the `listener` and `render` attributes from your `f:ajax`. Debug the setter for your property, it should be called.

Comment: With the "JSF 1.x workaround" I mean it's the same like `noSelectionOption="true"`. So I think this means nothing happens and it's not possible to choose it as value, since you mostly use it with e.g. a description. But in my case I want the value `null`. If I chosse this SelectItem after I choose a 'normal' SelectItem nothing happens neither the listener is called nor the setter. But I like to use `null` as a normal value.

Comment: do you wanna try itemValue="" and remove the noSelectionOption attribute ?